# Expression cannot be converted to long error

Tags: vb.net

im getting the following error, and have no idea how to solve this:
BC30581: Adressoff Expression cannot be converted to Long because Long is not a delegate type.

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (
ByVal HWnd As Long,
ByVal nIDEvent As Long,
ByVal uElapse As Long,
ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (
ByVal HWnd As Long,
ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single


Sub StartTimer()
    TimerSeconds = 1000 ' how often to "pop" the timer.
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer(0&, TimerID)
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long,
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

    MsgBox("test123")

End Sub
```

Comment: at which line are you getting the error ? Can you publish the rest of your code ?

Comment: this part will create the error: AddressOf TimerProc)

Comment: BC30581 is an error from the VB.NET compiler, are you sure you are programming in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your [PInvoke signature](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetTimer.html) is wrong.  Try this one instead:

```
Public Delegate Sub TimerProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uMsg As UInteger, ByVal nIDEvent As IntPtr, ByVal dwTime As UInteger)

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function SetTimer(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As IntPtr, ByVal uElapse As UInteger, ByVal lpTimerFunc As TimerProc) As IntPtr
End Function
```

You will need to change your pinvoke signature for `KillTimer` as well.  See pinvoke.net for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class TimerMethods

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetTimer(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As IntPtr, ByVal uElapse As UInteger, ByVal lpTimerFunc As TimerProc) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function KillTimer(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Delegate Sub TimerProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uMsg As UInteger, ByVal nIDEvent As IntPtr, ByVal dwTime As UInteger)

    Public timerID As IntPtr

    Sub StartTimer(windowHandle As IntPtr)
        Dim timerSeconds = 3 ' how often to "pop" the timer.
        timerID = SetTimer(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, CUInt(timerSeconds * 1000), AddressOf TimerMethods.TimerCallback)

        If timerID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Timer start error.")
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("Timer started.")
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub EndTimer()
        KillTimer(IntPtr.Zero, timerID)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub TimerCallback(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uMsg As UInteger, ByVal nIDEvent As IntPtr, ByVal dwTime As UInteger)
        MsgBox(uMsg)

    End Sub

End Class
```

and a simple form with just a button on it to start the timer:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim t As TimerMethods

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        t = New TimerMethods
        t.StartTimer(Me.Handle)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If t IsNot Nothing Then
            t.EndTimer()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

You don't have to use `windowHandle` to tie the timer to the form: you could use `IntPtr.Zero` instead.

Any time you see a variable name like `hWnd`, it wants a *handle*, which is an `IntPtr` in VB.NET.

Reference: [pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetTimer](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetTimer)

Answer (score 0):

There seems little point in using PInvoke to do this. There is a Windows Forms Timer that you can use easily:

```
Public Class Form3

    Private _timer As Timer

    Public Sub StartTimer()
        _timer = New Timer()
        _timer.Interval = 1000 ' timer interval in ms
        AddHandler _timer.Tick, AddressOf TimerProc
        _timer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndTimer()
        _timer.Enabled = False
        RemoveHandler _timer.Tick, AddressOf TimerProc
    End Sub

    Sub TimerProc(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("test123")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tested the code in VBE in Excel 2013 and run successfully.

Comment: sorry the title is not correct, i,m programming in VB.NET

Answer (score -1):

**I state beforehand that this solution is for `VBA` environment**

since that was a possible one at the stage I wrote it

I made it run with some edits:

- added the continuation escape sequence "`_`" at the end of each but the last line of `SetTimer()` and `KillTimer ()` function declaration
- in `EndTimer()` assigned `KillTimer` to a `Long` variable, which I also declared
- in `TimerProc()` added a call to EndTimer() to stop it !!!

here follows the working code for me:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
ByVal uElapse As Long, _
ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single


Sub StartTimer()
    TimerSeconds = 1000 ' how often to "pop" the timer.
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    Dim i As Long '<--| added
    On Error Resume Next
    i = KillTimer(0&, TimerID) '<--| added
End Sub


Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

    MsgBox ("test123")

    EndTimer '<--| added !!!
End Sub
```

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I was writing what above when it was being clarified that this was not a VBA environment. Please remove the down-vote. Thank you

Comment: Understood, but the answer is still incorrect for _this_ question.  Another VB.Net user might come across this answer and it will not work for them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But i still get the error of for the last part of the code:      TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you. Not to incur in further @ChrisDunaway most precise down-votes ...

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, my answer incipit is: "in VBA I made it run with some edits:". Isn't it sufficiently clear to any VB.Net user that might come across it?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, what's the problem in admitting my answer premise would prevent any VB.Net users harm, which was what you was afraid of?

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect for _this question_.  While the language being used was not clear when the question was posted, it is now clear that the language used is VB.Net.  Another user searching for this topic for VB.Ney might see your answer and mistakenly think it will work and it won't.  Why won't you correct  your answer so that it is correct for VB.Net?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, how can one mistakenly think it's VB.NET if the very first words of my answer are _"in `VBA`"_? I can't correct my answer because I don't know VB.NET

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I clearly exposed why nobody could get mistaken by my answer. Would you kindly remove your down votes? thank you